# MySQL Foreign key from equation of two rows value?

Tags: mysql, math

Hey guys I'm trying to set up a quick math table and figured I can save myself
some time if I created a foreign key that was the negation of two of my columns.
Probably a bad idea but I think it'd be a neat hat trick.

So lets say I have a table set up like this

```
ID    |    A    |    B    |    C (Foreign?)
0     |    5    |    3    |   (2)
```

So the simple math here is

`A-B=C`

I will never need more than a single row, but I will be querying this constantly through ajax to either update `A` or `B` or get the values of `A B & C` for display to the end user. I *COULD* always return something like this too, and I'm well aware of it

```
ID    |    A    |    B
0     |    5    |    3

SELECT A, B, (A-B) AS C 
FROM `sometable`
```

But I figure this would be a lot of  extra math on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you should write a before insert/update trigger on this table to emulate what you are trying to achieve.**

*That makes more sense and creating a foreign key for that is extremely BAD PRACTICE!*

You should read this,

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints

Comment: Good note, I will definitely follow it, I didn't assume a Foreign Key was the appropriate method, it was just a random though.